# Reset counter in jQuery function

Tags: javascript

Ok, this seems pretty basic but I'm stuck.

I'm setting a var outside of the loop, then increment and once the counter reaches a threshold I need to reset it back to 0.

```
var cnt = 0;
$("ul").each(function(cnt) {
    var ths = $(this),
        tul = ths.attr("id");
        
    cnt = cnt++;
       
    if (cnt == 20) {
        cnt = 0;
    }
...
});
```

For some reason it keeps incrementing till the end of the look. What am I missing?

Comment: What's the purpose of `tul`?.. Why are you doing `cnt = cnt++;` instead of `cnt = cnt+1;` or just `cnt += 1;` or just `cnt++;` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If cannot be reset to `0` because `cnt` is the **`.each(function(cnt) {`** function's **index** argument, and will always be the iterating index. You're trying to reset something to 0 which in the next loop will again be the index integer.

Depending on what's the desired (not clear from your question so far) you could simply **not use the index attribute**:

```js
let cnt = 0;

$("ul").each(function() {
  cnt += 1;
       
  if (cnt === 20) {
    cnt = 0;
  }

   // ...
});
```

### Modulo (reminder) operator

Use the reminder operator `%` to loop back to 0 once `idx` becomes 20.
In that case you don't need the outer variable, but you can use the iterating index attribute instead:

```js
$("ul").each(function(idx) {
  const cnt = idx % 20;  // Reset to 0 once idx is 20  

   // ... 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to the function is the index of the array. Checkout the jQuery documentation. https://api.jquery.com/each/

You do not need to pass the parameter to the function. See code below.

```
var cnt = 0;
$("ul").each(function() {        
    cnt++;
   
    if (cnt == 20) {    
        cnt = 0;
    }
});
```